# How to speed up resample procedure in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, resampling

Say you have a dataframe of 1 minute time series with index, 4 columns and 4 million rows. When you try to do something like:

```
 conversion = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}
 df1 = df.resample('5Min', how=conversion)
```

It takes an absurd amount of time (20-30 minutes). How can I speed up this process?

Pandas 18, Python 2.7

Comment: With randomly generated data (4 columns 4 million rows) it takes 247ms for me.

Comment: @ayhan Can you post the code you use to generate your data?

Comment: @ayhan, what `dtypes` did you generate? Could you post your code?

Comment: @hernanavella, did you get your data from internet (using `pandas_datareader `)? if so could you post the corresponding code, so we could test it on the same data?

Comment: @MaxU No, unfortunately that data is proprietary. Sorry. I'm double checking, bcs the loading the data could be contributing to the delay too.

Comment: index: `idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=4000000, freq='T')`, data: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4000000, 4), columns = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close"], index = idx)` test: `%timeit df.resample("5Min").agg(conversion)` (it was around the same with your code too)

Comment: @MaxU they are float64

Comment: @ayhan, yep, everything is correct. first i thought you are using `int`s for your test. Actually it took 315ms on my home laptop

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. I need to look for the source of the problem elsewhere.

Comment: @ayhan, i guess you can post your `prove snippet` as an answer - it shows that the `resample()` is not one to blame and IMO answers this question

Comment: @MaxU I couldn't be sure because in the index I generated values follow a regular pattern. If they are not regular or sorted it might take time to group them together maybe?

Comment: @ayhan, i've shuffled the DF (generated with your code) - `df = df.sample(len(df))` and now it takes  `2.45s` instead of `315ms` before on sorted index, but still it's far away from minutes

Comment: @MaxU You are correct. I could only increase it to 5 seconds.

Comment: Did you ever find what was causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resample seems to work quite fast on a dataset of size (4000000, 4):

```
idx = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=4000000, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4000000, 4), columns = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close"], index = idx)
%timeit df.resample("5Min").agg(conversion)
1 loop, best of 3: 253 ms per loop
```

With an irregular index and some nan's:

```
idx1 = pd.date_range('1/1/1900', periods=10000000, freq='Min')
idx2 = pd.date_range('1/1/1940', periods=10000000, freq='Min')
idx3 = pd.date_range('1/1/1980', periods=10000000, freq='Min')
idx4 = pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=10000000, freq='Min')
idx = np.array([np.random.choice(idx1, 1000000), np.random.choice(idx2, 1000000), np.random.choice(idx3, 1000000), 
                np.random.choice(idx4, 1000000)]).flatten()
np.random.shuffle(idx)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(4000000, 4)), columns = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close"], index = idx)
df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, 100000), "Open"] = np.nan
df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, 50000), "High"] = np.nan
df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, 500000), "Low"] = np.nan
df.loc[np.random.choice(idx, 20000), "Close"] = np.nan
%timeit df.resample("5Min").agg(conversion)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.06 s per loop
```

So it seems like something other than resample is taking time for your case.